# Compare two return values of object

Tags: java, oop

How do I compare two return values of an object? Because when I'm doing this in my code and the return values is different each time. Here is my code:

```
public static void Card_Initialization(){

 Red_Dog c1 = new Red_Dog();
 Red_Dog c2 = new Red_Dog();
 Cards_Match(c1);
 System.out.println(card_num+card_suit);
 Cards_Match(c2);
 System.out.println(card_num+card_suit);
 System.out.println(Cards_Match(c1) == Cards_Match(c2));//to check really if it is equal
 }

        public static int Cards_Match(Red_Dog rd){
            card = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length); 
             if(card >= 0 && card <=3)
         {
            card_num = cards[0];

         }
         else if(card >= 4 && card <=7)
         {
            card_num = cards[1];
         }
         else if(card >= 8 && card <=11)
         {
            card_num = cards[2];
         }
         else if(card >= 12 && card <=15)
         {
            card_num = cards[3];
         }
         else if(card >= 16 && card <=19)
         {
            card_num = cards[4];
         }
         else if(card >= 20 && card <=23)
         {
            card_num = cards[5];
         }
         else if(card >= 24 && card <=27)
         {
            card_num = cards[6];
         }
         else if(card >= 28 && card <=31)
         {
            card_num = cards[7];
         }
         else if(card >= 32 && card <=35)
         {
            card_num = cards[8];
         }
         else if(card >= 36 && card <=39)
         {
            card_num = cards[9];
         }
         else if(card >= 40 && card <=43)
         {
            card_num = cards[10];
         }
         else if(card >= 44 && card <=47)
         {
            card_num = cards[11];
         }
         else if(card >= 48 && card <=51)
         {
            card_num = cards[12];
         }

         if(card % 4 == 0)
         {
            card_suit = suits[0];
         }

         else if(card % 4 == 1)
         {
            card_suit = suits[1];
         }

         else if(card % 4 == 2)
         {
            card_suit = suits[2];
         }

         else if(card % 4 == 3)
         {
            card_suit = suits[3];
         }

         return card;   
        }
```

Result:
1st run:
AceSpades
AceSpades
false

2nd run:
AceSpades
AceSpades
true

Comment: Share you source codes for Red_Dog class and Cards_Match method.

Comment: Waht is `Cards_Match()`?

Comment: Hi, I posted the code in here: http://shrib.com/red_dog_card 
You can access it there.

Answer (score 3):

In java (and many pass by reference languages), the == operator compares the memory location where the objects are stored. Because these are two different objects, they are stored in different memory locations.

You need to use a .equals() method like this:

```
c1.equals(c2)
```

You will need to write the equals method of your class to check if the cards equal each other, in this case by comparing both their number and suit.

Comment: I made the changes but it's still the same. Result still vary:

Result: 1st run: AceSpades AceSpades false

2nd run: AceSpades AceSpades true

Comment: I changed it to this:
System.out.println(c1.equals(c2));

but result is still the same.

Comment: Cards_Match is not an object in OP's code.

Comment: Did you define your equals method within your card class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change this :

```
 System.out.println(Cards_Match(c1) == Cards_Match(c2));
```

to

```
 System.out.println(c1.equals(c2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your naming got us confused. **Cards_Match is not an object is a method**!

A method that generates **random** numbers depending on objects that you have not included in your question. If you compare generated random int numbers, you are going to obtain different results each time.

I think that you are trying to implement: pick a card 1 randomly, pick another card 2 randomly and then compare then. But it's not working with the rest of your program.

Please use java naming conventions in the future. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: oh I'm sorry about that. I will use naming conventions for future use. thanks for reminding me. so in the question, how can I compare two random values?

Comment: You can compare then but you will obtain different results. You have to change your algorithm. Implement an object Card with a method equals and another method to pick a card randomly from the deck, then compare the two obtained cards.

Comment: Object Card will contain card_num and card_suit. Your equals method just have to return if two Cards have the same card_num and card_suit.